# How to turn WIFI radio on?

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) the Wi-Fi radio may turn off when the user has not used the device in a while. Acquiring a WifiLock will keep the radio on until the lock is released, however holding a WifiLock adversely affects battery life. So is there any way to turn the wifi radio back on when it was turned off by the system?

Comment: I don't see any difference in battery between keeping WifiLock and constantly enabling WiFi when it turns off. If want to use wi-fi constantly, you should acquire a WiFi lock.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to turn WiFi on every time it turns off? Or a way to turn it on when you need it? Either way, get a WiFi lock when you need WiFi, and release the lock when you don't need WiFi.

The reason that a WiFi lock drains the battery is because it may be keeping the WiFi on when it's not actually necessary. But if your goal is to keep the WiFi on, then avoiding a WiFi lock won't help the battery situation.